# Python not logging error output

Tags: python, exception, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook to develop some Python.  This is my first stab at logging errors and I'm having an issue where no errors are logged to my error file.

I'm using:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('error')
logger.propagate = False
hdlr = logging.FileHandler("error.log")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

to create the logger.

I'm then using a try/Except block which is being called on purpose (for testing) by using a column that doesn't exist in my database:

```
try:
    some_bad_call_to_the_database('start',group_id)
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception("an error I would like to log")
    print traceback.format_exc(limit=1)
```

and the exception is called as can be seen from my output in my notebook:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-10-ef8532b8e6e0>", line 19, in <module>
some_bad_call_to_the_database('start',group_id)
InternalError: (1054, u"Unknown column 'start_times' in 'field list'")
```

However, error.log is not being written to.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
except Exception as e:
    excep = logger.info("an error I would like to log")
```

for more information please look at the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

have a great day!

Comment: That did it!  Coming from PHP, I'm getting used to the idea of the level of the logging affecting the output.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `logging.exception`, which delegates to the root logger, instead of using `logger.exception`, which would use yours (and write to `error.log`).

Comment: I've updated the code to use logger.exception and unfortunately, there still is no output.

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug with the database call, so I tried it with manually raising a ``ValueError`` and it worked.